# WCF IParameterInspector + IErrorHandler

Tags: .net, wcf, error-handling, wcf-4, wcf-extensions

If I have both [`IParameterInspector`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iparameterinspector.aspx) and [`IErrorHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.ierrorhandler.aspx) attached to a service can I be sure [`IErrorHandler.HandleError()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.ierrorhandler.handleerror.aspx) will be called on the same thread where [`IParameterInspector.BeforeCall()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iparameterinspector.beforecall.aspx) is called?

I need this because in case of a fault thrown [`IParameterInspector.AfterCall()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iparameterinspector.aftercall.aspx) is never called and there is no way (as far as I know) I can get correlation state object created in `BeforeCall()`. So I hope to overcome this by having a `ThreadStatic` field in my implementation of the interfaces :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want to utilize Instance Context Extensions.

```
InstanceContextExtension: IExtension<InstanceContext>   
OperationContext.Current.InstanceContext.Extensions.Find<InstanceContextExtension>()
```

The instance context extension can be added in `BeforeCall` method. The instance context extension can then be retrieved in `AfterCall` method and used. Any operation specific data can be put in this extension object instead of introducing thread affinity.

Comment: I'm not sure OperationContext is accessible in IErrorHandler.HandleError(). Tried similar approach few days ago and got ObjectDisposedException :(

Comment: Just a thought, would creating correlation state in `AfterReceiveRequest` method of `IDispatchMessageInspector` interface would be good idea?

Comment: I've realized I can use ProvideFault() instead of HandleError() so your approach looks the best! +1

Answer (score 2):

You could have your class that implements IErrorHandler also implement IParameterInspector. You could then store references to your correlation state and input parameters as class variables. Then they would be accessable from within the HandleError method. I'm currently using this for logging input parameters and the raw message whenever an unhandled exception occurs.

Comment: That's exactly what i'm doing. However, I'd like to be sure this will be thread safe.

Comment: Is your service InstanceContextMode PerCall? If so I believe you would get a new instance of the service and the ErrorHandler for that service for each call.